# Using D3.nest() to create an array of objects by column header

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js

I have a CSV file with the format:

time,group1,group2,group3
0,45,30,30,
1,30,25,31,
2,50,45,30,

I want to structure it as an array of objects such that :
`[{group1:array[3]}, {group2:array[3]},...]`
where each `array[3]` is itself an array of objects that pairs 
the value in the time column with the value in its respective group column 
i.e. :
group1 `[{time:0, value:45},{time:1, value:30},...]` group2 `[{time:0, value:30},...]`

D3.csv parses by row  and I'm not sure how to iterate through the resulting array of objects with d3.nest or if there's a way to set up the data structure within the d3.csv accessor function. (I apologize if I'm using terms improperly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `d3.nest()` to do this. You could just loop over the parsed csv file to put the data in the format you need. For instance:

```
var csv = "time,group1,group2,group3\n0,45,30,30\n1,30,25,31\n2,50,45,30";
var data = d3.csv.parse(csv);
var result = [ {group1: []}, {group2: []}, {group3: []}]

data.forEach(function(d) {
    result[0]['group1'].push({time: +d.time, value: +d['group1']})
    result[1]['group2'].push({time: +d.time, value: +d['group2']})
    result[2]['group3'].push({time: +d.time, value: +d['group3']})
});
```

This isn't the most flexible example (since the columns are hardcoded) but hopefully it will give you an idea of how to go about it.